# $\int_{0}^{e}\frac{\sin(\operatorname{W(x)})-1}{\sin(\operatorname{W(x)})+1}\frac{\sin(\operatorname{2W(x)})-1}{\sin(\operatorname{2W(x)})+1}dx=?$

Tags: definite-integrals, residue-calculus, hypergeometric-function, trigonometric-integrals, lambert-w

> Solve the following integral :
>   $$\int_{0}^{e}\frac{\sin(\operatorname{W(x)})-1}{\sin(\operatorname{W(x)})+1}\frac{\sin(\operatorname{2W(x)})-1}{\sin(\operatorname{2W(x)})+1}dx=?$$

---

My attempt:

We are lucky because there exists [an antiderivative](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=primitive%20%28sin%28W%28x%29%29-1%29%2F%28sin%28W%28x%29%29%2B1%29%28sin%282W%28x%29%29%2B1%29%2F%28sin%282W%28x%29%29-1%29%20) in terms of [Hypergeometric function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunction.html) and [generalized Hypergeometric function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedHypergeometricFunction.html)

I have tried the obvious substitution $\operatorname{W(x)}=t$ and integration by parts, but it generates integrals where I can't find the issue.

Moreover, I have tried to reveal some Gamma function but I can't.

Finally, I think (it's just an intuition) that we can use complex integral and [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem).

If you could help me, I would be thankful.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

*You seem to like Lambert function as much as I do !*

Concerning the integral, make $$W(x)=t \implies x=t\, e^t\implies dx=(1+t)\, e^t$$ and then we face the problem of
$$\int_0^1 \frac{(\sin (t)-1)\, (\sin (2 t)-1)}{(\sin (t)+1)\, (\sin (2 t)+1)} \,(t+1)\, e^t\,dt$$ As you wrote, there is a messy antiderivative and the definite integral express in terms of a bunch of hypergeometric functions and Hurwitz-Lerch functions.

Evaluated, the result is
  $$0.21053628117921200861$$ which is not recognized by inverse symbolic calculators.

If you want a meaningless approximation
$$\frac{541+596 \pi -212 \pi ^2}{361+449 \pi -25 \pi ^2}=0.21053628117921200854$$